# Malloc an array with Rust Layout

Tags: rust

My current code:

```
use std::alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout};

unsafe {
  let n = 0x10000; // I get this value from a function
  let layout = Layout::new::<[u8; n]>();// n is non-constant value issue E0435 E0425
  let mut ptr = alloc(layout);
  *(ptr as *mut u8) = 42;
}
```

What if I want to allocate 0x10000 of heap? I have read [Layout documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/alloc/struct.Layout.html) but I miss the example about allocating more than one u8. (`Layout::new::<u8>` works fine)

Is it the best way to allocate memory (unsafely) in Rust? Also what would be the best safe way to do it ?

Alternatively I have been using (which works very well):

```
let n = 0x10000;
let mut v<u8>; = Vec::with_capacity(n);
unsafe { v.set_len(n); }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use unsafe code to allocate memory? Why are safe methods not sufficient?

Comment: I am interested to learn both ways, as they can be used for different usecases.

Comment: Between this and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66610639/3650362), it seems that you are facing some problem with initializing buffers, but you haven't actually asked *that* question, just questions about how you think it *should* work. Using the allocator API is unusual in Rust, so if you have a problem where you think you need it, you should ask about *that* problem rather than asking about the allocator API itself. `MaybeUninit` might be the answer, or maybe there's another standard API that solves your problem more specifically than falling back to raw pointers.

Comment: The direct answer to "how to allocate an array with `std::alloc`" is use [`Layout::array<u8>(n)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/alloc/struct.Layout.html#method.array) for the layout.

Comment: You asked: "Is this the best way to allocate memory (unsafely) in Rust?" and "what would be the best safe way to do it?" The answers to *both* questions are: **Use `Vec` instead.** The answers to the other question adequately cover this, which is why I marked it a duplicate. Arguably, I should perhaps have instead voted to close as "needs focus", since it contains multiple questions; however, I feel the two questions actually do have the same answer, which is that `Vec` is the safe and idiomatic way to allocate an array in Rust, so I treated it as if you had asked that question directly.

Comment: yes I had also realized this and wanted to cancel reopening but it was too late. Apologies.

Comment: @kmdreko thanks, I ended up using `layout = Layout::from_size_align_unchecked(n, mem::align_of::<u8>());` would it make any difference with your suggestion?

Comment: @trentcl I think it might have been a bit over zealous to mark this as a duplicate; the linked question does not address array allocations using alloc, and the solution to *this* quesiton is posted here as a comment by kmdreko. I found this very annoying that the answer listed below is irrelevant to the question, and that the linked question does not address the question asked here.

Comment: @Doug As I mentioned in my earlier comments, the question has multiple issues, *including* that the direct use of the `Layout` API probably isn't what the asker actually needed given the context given the user's other questions. But one can only pick one close reason and I have given my reasons why I believe "duplicate" is appropriate. If you can write a focused question about the `alloc` API which is not encumbered with other problems, I will be happy to upvote it

Comment: @trentcl given that the title is literally "Malloc an array with Rust Layout" it does turn up in search results as such. Well, you're the moderator who made the call; I'm just pointing out 'close everything as duplicate' is not correct approach, and was probably the wrong call in this case. Question could have been refined to remove ambiguity instead.

Comment: It's annoying that this has been closed, and worse, with an irrelevant answer, since there are use cases for this approach. In my case, I'm porting a C codebase to Rust, and I need to eliminate libc calls first. The answer to this question can be found here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/vec/vec-alloc.html, and it's `let layout = Layout::array::<u8>(n).unwrap(); let ptr = alloc(layout);`

Answer (score 1):

To allocate a slice of `size` items of type `T`, you should just create a vector of them:

```rust
// resizable vector of 0x10000 items:
let vec: Vec<u8> = vec![0u8; 0x10000];

// unique pointer (Box) to a fixed-slice of 0x10000 items:
let boxed_slice: Box<[u8]> = vec![0u8; 0x10000].into_boxed_slice();
```

Note that this initialized each value of the array to `0`, which is necessary because Rust generally expects values to be initialized (and uninitialized memory can lead to undefined behavior, even for integer types like `u8`).

Generally speaking, I'd also recommend that you avoid using `std::mem::alloc` directly in your code. When using it, you need to think more carefully about how you handle memory, there's more room for mistakes, and there are rarely any significant advantages over the safe variant above. Even if you want to allocate uninitialized memory and initialize it yourself, you're likely better off with `Vec<MaybeUninit<T>>` or `Box<[MaybeUninit<T>]`, which provide a safer (but still unsafe) interface for uninitialized memory.

Comment: The reason why I want to know about the unsafe alternative is because I want to create a very big buffer (hence not on the stack). However I dont want to initialize the values of this buffer (it is a buffer, values will be replaced). There is no safe way to have a heap allocated buffer uninitialized? Could you develop about `Box<[MaybeUninit<T>` ?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL [Here's an example of using `MaybeUninit` with a `Vec` to initialize a buffer from a closure in reverse order](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a0c0fa08cf2fd04117cc5379a78745a8). It's missing [some nightly features that make it less `unsafe`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=898b124b629968f0fe6232866d4194f6), but perhaps you can adapt this general idea to your code.